AWS DynamicFrame.Map Returning No Rows
I have the following code as part of an ETL script.
def UpdateRec(rec):
  rec["LoanNumber_ERROR"] = rec["LoanNumber"] + " IS INVALID"
  return rec

my_dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(my_df,glueContext,"my_df")
final_dyf = my_dyf.map(f=UpdateRec)

print(f'Initial row count is: {my_df.count()}')
print(f'Final row count is: {final_dyf.count()}')

Running this gives the following output:
Initial row count is: 5
Final row count is: 0

There are no errors running this, but it is NOT what I was expecting. Commenting out the one line in UpdateRec allows the Map command to return the expected number of rows (5), but I need this to do some transformations on the input record.
Additional context: I'm developing this bit of code in an AWS Glue Studio Notebook.

I'm posting what I did to solve this. I'm sure there are better answers to come!
It turns out that rec["LoanNumber"] is a long and python doesn't like adding a long with a string (no surprise). I had to convert it to a string to get this to work. Super simple and obvious, but there wasn't anything on SO that lead me to this, which is why I posted the question & answer. Here's the updated code:
def UpdateRec(rec):
  rec["LoanNumber_ERROR"] = str(rec["LoanNumber"]) + " IS INVALID"
  return rec

The frustrating part is that there was no error reporting that my original function was bombing out causing Map to return no rows. Long story short: beware of hidden errors while working in Glue Studio I guess.

This took me 5 hours to figure out.
The .map() function suppresses any exception raised within the mapping
The stageThreshold and totalThreshold don't work for me
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-map
